# Cannot find mule --> Manage APIs in anypoint studio 7

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule4

I'm doing training of Mule4. In WT-5 of module 4 I have to add API from exchange. But I cannot find mule--> manage API option. Don't know what to do.

Really appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of Version. I was using AnypointStudio 7.1. I updated my version to 7.4 and now I can see the option

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the API Manager / Manage API from Exchange function. It is mentioned in the documentation at https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/manage-exchange-api-task:

> 1. Click API Manager in tne Anypoint Platform navigation bar. API Administration opens in your default environment, such as Sandbox.
> 2. List item  In API Administration, select Manage API > Manage API From Exchange.